# Is there a library to do CSS spriting automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, optimization

CSS Spriting can really help performance, but it's not the easiest thing to read and maintain.  Are there any tools that would let me code the images individually but aggregate them up and replace the HTML with the correct subset of the montage?

I'm specifically thinking a Ruby on Rails plugin, but if there's a package for another language, I'd be happy to port it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but image_bundle appears to be what you want:

http://github.com/bartt/image_bundle/tree/master

Answer (score 5):

[SmartSprites](http://smartsprites.osinski.name/)

Try it.

Comment: "Step 1 - code the site as you would regularly. Step 5 - Check to make sure your design still works. Chances are, it won't."

Where's the time-saving part?

Comment: I like it, but I'm not quite sold yet.  It's a _good_ answer.  I'm awaiting others before awarding "best."

Comment: I just looked through the instructions... Shit! It would take way less time to do it manually!

Answer (score 0):

image_bundle is only for RMagick.
I am trying to port it over to imagescience.

Comment: Please use the "comment" feature to reply to others, instead of making a new answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow!